How can I use a project that has been installed with pip install -e .?
I am using a project (originally from github) that in its readme says:

To use:

Clone the project
Create a virtual environment
Do pip install --upgrade pip and pip install -e .


I have tried the project, it is working well. I read briefly that this install the project in "editable" mode.
Anyway, I am ready to create a project in a repo of my own, in which I would write python scripts. This scripts will use the original project above
Something like
from pathlib import Path
from originalP.eval.run_EXP import eval_multiple
from originalP.mm_utils import get_model_name_from_path
import pandas as pd 

My question is how can I use originalP in my own repo?

What I did so far is

Created my project root folder
Created a virtual environment with python -m venv MyPVenv
Activated the virtual environment with source MyPVenv/bin/activate

Just to check, here I do python -c "import gradio" and of course it says it is not installed
My doubt comes from here

I did pip install -e /path/to/originalP

After I do this, I check python -c "import gradio" and yes, gradio is installed (because originalP uses gradio)
Is this how it is done?
I have high doubts because what if in my project I want to use one library - for example gradio- with a newer version?
In the originalP for example the gradio version is 4.16.0 but I want to use something newer.
Am I going to be tied to the versions the originalP uses?

Only if you have two different (virtual) environments can you have two different version of the same library/dependency/application. -- So yes, the typical use case is to have one (virtual) environment per project (or per application). -- What you have done so far seems correct. -- This page should be reliable (there is A LOT of bad advice on the web). -- I also recommend skipping the activation of virtual environments and instead use full paths, like path/to/venv/bin/python -m pip install --editable /path/to/originalP.

I did some reading. As it seems there are some solutions, but they all require some level of unsustainable "hacks". As it appears it's not supported natively.
You have a choice to make here. I think if you want to run two different versions of a module at once, it's generally better to update your code or use segmentation in the form of docker containers or api calls.
Your question is the same as asked here
There are some ways to get around this but its generally not recommended.
See these threads: medium, reddit, python forum,

A pip editable install is sometimes called a "developer" install as this is only required when you are going to be changing the files in the project you are installing.
You can install from local disk without it being editable. e.g.
pip install /path/to/originalP

If you want to install directly from a github repo then you can do something like:
pip install git+ssh://git@github.com/github_user/github_repo.git

You can even specify the github url as a requirement of your project.
From what you have written it would appear that originalP project has a requirement of gradio at a specific older version while you want to use a newer version.
Python is designed not to support multiple version of a module at the same time.
Best practice is that sub modules don't lock specific versions unless absolutely necessary. While top-level projects lock the version of all the dependencies it uses.
Could it be that originalP was expected to be a top-level project and so has locked the version of all dependencies but could work with a newer version of gradio?
Have you tried upgrading the version gradio and seeing if your project still works?
